# For what integer $m$ and $n$ is $\tan(m \, \arctan(x) + n \, \arctan(y))$ a rational function of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-functions

> For what values of $n,m \in N$ is $$\tan(m \, \arctan(x) + n \, \arctan(y))$$ rational?
>
> I.e., what $n$ and $m$ values would allow me to simplify the expression above to a rational expression in $F[x,y]$, where $F$ is a ring or a field.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried expanding the whole thing using expand_trig (in Sage), and then I expanded the result even further using the expand command, in order to get a normal form. But I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: How about using the tangent angle addition identity first?

Comment: expand_trig() expands expressions like $sin(a + b)$ and $cos(a +b)$. However, I don't know if this command does the same for $tan(a + b)$.

Comment: I managed to get an expression that looks as follows: $P(x,y) / Q(x,y)$, where P,Q are both polynomials in $F[x,y]$.

Comment: Have you tried drawing it?

Comment: No, because I don't see how a plot would help in that case. Do you have something specific in mind for how I can extract information like this out of a plot?

Comment: Are there any properties of a ring or a field that allow for a slick manipulation?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. That's why i'm asking.

Comment: Are you aware of the tangent addition formula $$\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a \tan b}\quad?$$ From this, it is easy to find that$$\tan\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\arctan(x_i)\right)$$ is a rational function of $x_1,\dots,x_n$.